# Xamarin Binding SWIFT lib: SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE when constructor has params

Tags: swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind a SWIFT library to Xamarin iOS.
Source code has class:

```swift
@objc(ClassA)
public class ClassA: NSObject {
    // ...
    public init(param1: StructA, param2: EnumStringA = .defaultValueA) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

but in *-Swift.h file it looks like this:

```objectivec
SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED("ClassA")
@interface ClassA: NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (nonnull instancetype)new SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE_MSG("-init is unavailable");
@end
```

So, of course, Sharpie tool make the interface empty, without constructor:

```cs
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[DisableDefaultCtor]
interface ClassA
{
}
```

I thought maybe its because both StructA and EnumStringA are not exposed, but `@objc` attribute is not applicable for `struct` and for `enum : String`

How to make the constructor is visible?

Comment: You could post the issue to github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: ok, but i'm not sure if it is xamarin bug https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13230

Comment: I think this is not a bug after all. All arguments in Init() must be @objc compatible.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to having the `@objc` attribute on the protocol that was in my (only) `init` argument, I had to add the `@objc` attribute to my `init` method itself, such that it looks something like this (using the OP example):

```
@objc
public init(param1: MyProtocol) {
<...>
}
```

This output the expected code in the `*-Swift.h` file.

Comment: well... this is very old question so i can't confirm if the answer is correct anymore.

Comment: Well, this solved my problem anyway, which was the same problem as you described. This will at least be helpful to me if I need to come back to it.